# Android: TTS Engine is destroyed when same instance of activity is used with FLAG: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP from Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use TTS Engine along with Broadcast Engine.

My Activity is `A`, and the broad cast receiver is `B`. I am enabling activity `A` when ever there is a new message, and when there is another message them i will call start activity `A` again from `B` using "`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`", since i am clearing the top instances, even though the old `A` is destroyed and the new A is created the TTS Engine is also destroyed along with the old `A`. Please Help

```
public class SMSPopup extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

String smsMessageId = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    displayPopupSMS();
    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            return;
        }
        if (!readMessageText.contains("null")) {
            Log.i("SMS Message", "Call from init" + readMessageText);
            readSMS();
        }
    }
}

private void readSMS() {
    mTts.speak(readMessageText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mTts!=null){
        mTts.shutdown();
    }
}
```

}

If i am not shutting down the TTS in `onDestroy()` function it is leaking the TTS Service.

Comment: From : Broadcast reveiver
smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(smsIntent);